# comparing cells to a any cells in a given column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following columns in Excel.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to get data from two sets of column transferred to another set of column if their first column cell matches. So in the screenshot since boy has 100 in column I. it should transfer the 100 to Column C where Boy Row is.

I figured out a away to do it in Java using loops but I thought there might be an easier way of doing it directly in excel.

Comment: you  can use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: @Susilo, that seems to be the answer. However, what's inconvenient is that when I copy the formula to propagate to the rows in C, I have to keep changing the table array in the look up formula to always match H1:I2. Is there an easier way of copying the formula so that only the lookup value cell changes and not all cells in the formula?

Comment: i figured out absolute referencing is the x answer to my second question. So all my questions are answered. If you'd like to change your comment as Answer, it be happy to accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Although Vlookup is a formula that will work for your needs, it does come with some [limitations](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/). Better start using the best way from the start, which is nesting a Match formula in an Index one. With the example provided above:

```
=Index(I:I,Match(B:B,H:H,0))
```